# Почему в слове обожженный пишется 2 ж?

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что они есть в исходном бесприставочном "жжёный", "жжёт".
Вот откуда второе ж взялось в "жжёный" - это уже вопрос интересный. 
Основа всех слов и форм - праславянское "жьг". В наиболее полном виде оно сохранилось в форме "жгу" - с выпадением беглой гласной. В инфинитиве это Г под влиянием особых процессов в русском языке (палатализации) перешло в Ч - жечь. А вот в формах "жжет", "жжёный" Г уподобилось предшествующему Ж (это тоже закономерный процесс). С выпадением беглой гласной получилось два Ж подряд.